# How to select from only where all intervals have values?

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to select from table where all 15 minute intervals have a value for each channel else do not select that interfval. Table:

[image]

Results should be:

[image]

So interval 201905151300 should not be included since there is no channel 2 value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be looking for four records for each time.  You can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by id, datetime) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt = 4;
```

If you don't know the number of channels, you can use:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by id, datetime) as cnt,
             count(distinct channel) over () as num_channel
      from t
     ) t
where cnt = num_channel;
```

Comment: I was able to get the count from a different master table. Your solution worked. Thank you very much. I am not familiar with the over and partition by functions, so I need to try and brush up on my coding.

Answer (score 0):

Try This-

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE DateTime IN
(
    SELECT DateTime
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY DateTime
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Chanel) = 4
)
```